# Spell-Storing weapon + Magus' Spellstrike

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, magic, spellcasting, magus

Okay, I've seen a few questions about this but not the exact question I have so I figure it's reasonable to ask.

Let's assume the following situation, I have a [magus](https://www.aonprd.com/ClassDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Magus) with a [spell-storing weapon](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWeaponsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Spell%20Storing) with, let's say, Frigid Touch stored in it. I enter combat and cast Shocking grasp using my standard action, move to my target and use Spellstrike to take the free touch attack I get with Shocking grasp to deliver the spell through my weapon.

Assuming I hit, I deal weapon damage + the damage of Shocking Grasp, let's assume a 5th level magus wielding a rapier and say this is 1d6 piercing + 5d6 electricity.

As I have hit my target with my weapon and dealt weapon damage, can I now use a follow-up free action to discharge the stored Frigid Touch using the Spell-Storing element of the weapon for an additional 4d6 cold damage and a chance to stagger the enemy?

Or do I have to choose to discharge the stored spell OR use Spellstrike?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what leads to the belief that it could be *or* instead of just being *and*?

Comment: Honestly? The fact that it feels broken to be able to dish out 10d6 damage in one round at level 5?

Comment: Fair enough. A magus 5 can typically cast 5 1st-level and 3 2nd-level spells per day. Expending 20% of one pile of resources, maybe 1/3 of another pile of resources to deal an extra 10d6 damage once per combat (because then *frigid touch* must be cast into the weapon again) seems about right to me. Maybe try factoring in that over 80% of the character's WBL is tied up in that *+1 spell storing rapier* and the balance is more pronounced?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spellstrike doesn’t have any special interaction with *spell storing*, which is to say, you can use *spell storing* as normal after hitting someone with your weapon, whether that hit was done using spellstrike or any other means.<sup>1</sup> As long as you’ve hit someone with the *spell storing* weapon, and it’s still your turn, you are allowed to use the spell in the weapon. The only way something **could** prevent you from using the spell is if it explicitly said you can’t use *spell storing* with it—and as far as I know, nothing in the game says that.

1. <sub>Attacks of opportunity are questionable—you generally cannot take free actions outside your turn, and it’s not clear if the “interruption” offered by an attack of opportunity is an exception to this or not. I generally feel the game works better if it is, but *spell storing* is definitely one of the cases where I can see why a GM wouldn’t want it to.</sub>